# How to update state of parent widget from child

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I have been trying to make a custom drawer using Animated Container. When I put each animated container as a child in AnimatedSwitcher (Menu, Cheatsheet, Reference) conditionally, it displays everything. THERE IS NO UPDATE when I segregate each animated container in a stateful widget and then pass it to the child of AnimatedSwitcher. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the main.dart for reference, I am passing the DrawerControllerMain in line 87

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:regex_query/Drawers/main_drawer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.black87,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFFFFD),
      drawerTheme: const DrawerThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF85F4FF),
        elevation: 20,
      ),
    ),
    darkTheme: ThemeData(),
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => const RegexQuery(),
    },
  ));
}

class RegexQuery extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegexQuery({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegexQuery> createState() => _RegexQueryState();
}

class _RegexQueryState extends State<RegexQuery> {
  final Color _backgroundColor = const Color(0xFFEFFFFD);
  
  bool expanded = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final _screenWidth = _screenSize.width;
    final _screenHeight = _screenSize.height;

return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
  body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFC8FFDE),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'Regex Query Tool',
            style: GoogleFonts.stalinistOne(
                textStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 30)),
          ),
          leading: Text(
            '.*',
            style: GoogleFonts.xanhMono(
                textStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 45)),
          ),
          actions: [
            Text(
              '*. ',
              style: GoogleFonts.xanhMono(
                  textStyle:
                      const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 45)),
            ),
          ],
          toolbarHeight: 1000,
        ),
        width: _screenWidth,
        height: 50,
      ),
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [DrawerControllerMain()]),
    ],
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Here is the file main_drawer.dart

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:regex_query/main.dart' as main;

class DrawerControllerMain extends StatefulWidget {
  const DrawerControllerMain({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DrawerControllerMain> createState() => _DrawerControllerMainState();
}

class _DrawerControllerMainState extends State<DrawerControllerMain> {
  bool expanded = true;
  Map<String, bool> drawerControllerMapping = {
    "Menu": true,
    "Cheatsheet": false,
    "References": false,
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: drawerControllerMapping['Cheatsheet'] == true
            ? CheatsheetDrawer(
                drawerControllerMapping: drawerControllerMapping,
                function: () {
                  setState(() {
                    drawerControllerMapping['Cheatsheet'] = true;
                  });
                },  
              )
            :
            // References Drawer...
            drawerControllerMapping['References'] == true
                ? ReferenceDrawer(
                    drawerControllerMapping: drawerControllerMapping,
                    function: () {
                      setState(() {
                        drawerControllerMapping['References'] = true;
                      });
                    },
                  )
                : MenuDrawer(
                    drawerControllerMapping: drawerControllerMapping,
                    function: () {
                      setState(() {
                        drawerControllerMapping['Menu'] = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ));
          }
        } 

class MenuDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  Map drawerControllerMapping;
  final Function function;

  MenuDrawer(
      {Key? key, required this.drawerControllerMapping, required this.function})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MenuDrawer> createState() => _MenuDrawerState();
}

class _MenuDrawerState extends State<MenuDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final _screenWidth = _screenSize.width;
    final _screenHeight = _screenSize.height;
    bool expanded = true;
    const _drawerColor = Color(0xFFD6FFF4);

void drawerUpScale() {
  setState(() {
    expanded = !expanded;
  });
}

return AnimatedContainer(
  key: const Key('1'),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  curve: Curves.easeOutExpo,
  height: _screenHeight - 50,
  width: expanded ? 450 : 65,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: _drawerColor),
  child: Column(children: [
    ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.menu,
        size: 30,
      ),
      title: expanded
          ? const Text(
              'Menu',
            )
          : null,
      onTap: () {
        drawerUpScale();
      },
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.view_column_outlined,
        size: 30,
      ),
      title: expanded
          ? const Text(
              'Cheatsheet',
            )
          : null,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.function;
        });
      },
    ),
    ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.auto_stories_sharp,
        size: 30,
      ),
      title: expanded
          ? const Text(
              'References',
            )
          : null,
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          widget.function;
        });
      },
    ),
  ]),
);
  }
}

class ReferenceDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  var drawerControllerMapping;
  final Function function;

  ReferenceDrawer(
      {Key? key, required this.drawerControllerMapping, required this.function})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReferenceDrawer> createState() => _ReferenceDrawerState();
}

class _ReferenceDrawerState extends State<ReferenceDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final _screenWidth = _screenSize.width;
    final _screenHeight = _screenSize.height;
    bool expanded = true;
    const _drawerColor = Color(0xFFD6FFF4);
    void drawerUpScale() {
      setState(() {
        expanded = !expanded;
      });
    }

return AnimatedContainer(
  key: Key('2'),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  curve: Curves.easeOutExpo,
  height: _screenHeight - 50,
  width: expanded ? 450 : 65,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: _drawerColor),
  child: Column(children: [
    ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
          size: 30,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            this.widget.drawerControllerMapping['References'] = false;
          });
        }),
    ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.auto_stories_sharp,
        size: 30,
      ),
      title: expanded
          ? const Text(
              'References',
            )
          : null,
      onTap: () {
        drawerUpScale();
      },
    ),
  ]),
);
  }
}

class CheatsheetDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  var drawerControllerMapping;
  final Function function;

  CheatsheetDrawer(
      {Key? key, this.drawerControllerMapping, required this.function})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheatsheetDrawer> createState() => _CheatsheetDrawerState();
}

class _CheatsheetDrawerState extends State<CheatsheetDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final _screenWidth = _screenSize.width;
    final _screenHeight = _screenSize.height;
    bool expanded = true;
    const _drawerColor = Color(0xFFD6FFF4);
    void drawerUpScale() {
      setState(() {
        expanded = !expanded;
      });
    }

return AnimatedContainer(
  key: Key('2'),
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  curve: Curves.easeOutExpo,
  height: _screenHeight - 50,
  width: expanded ? 450 : 65,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: _drawerColor),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
              size: 30,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                this.widget.drawerControllerMapping['Cheatsheet'] = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(
              Icons.view_column_outlined,
              size: 30,
            ),
            title: expanded
                ? const Text(
                    'Cheatsheet',
                  )
                : null,
            onTap: () {
              drawerUpScale();
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          InkWell(
              onTap: () => print('Character Classes'),
              child: Container(
                child: const Text('Character Classes'),
                color: Colors.indigo,
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                width: 450,
              )),
          ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              // ListTile(title: Container(child: const Text('Character Classes'), color: Colors.indigo, padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),), tileColor: Colors.indigo,),
              ListTile(
                title: Table(
                  defaultVerticalAlignment:
                      TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(5),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(100),
                  },
                  children: const [
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(
                        '.',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                      Text('Any Character except newline'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\w \d \s'),
                      Text('word, digit, whitespace'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\W \D \S'),
                      Text('NOT word, digit, whitespace'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('[abc]'),
                      Text(
                        'any of a, b, or c',
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('[^abc]'),
                      Text('not a, b, or c'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('[a-g]'),
                      Text('character between a & g'),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print('Anchors'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text('Anchors'),
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                    width: 450,
                  )),
              ListTile(
                title: Table(
                  defaultVerticalAlignment:
                      TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(5),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(100),
                  },
                  children: const [
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'^ , $'),
                      Text('Start / End of the string'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\b \B'),
                      Text('word, not-word boundary'),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print('Escaped Characters'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text('Escaped Characters'),
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                    width: 450,
                  )),
              ListTile(
                title: Table(
                  defaultVerticalAlignment:
                      TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(5),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(100),
                  },
                  children: const [
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\. \* \\'),
                      Text('escaped special characters'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\t \n \r'),
                      Text('tab, linefeed, carriage return'),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print('Groups and LookAround'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text('Groups and LookAround'),
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                    width: 450,
                  )),
              ListTile(
                title: Table(
                  defaultVerticalAlignment:
                      TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(5),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(100),
                  },
                  children: const [
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('(abc)'),
                      Text('capture group'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'\1'),
                      Text('back-reference to group #1'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'(?:abc)'),
                      Text('non-capturing group'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('(?=abc)'),
                      Text(
                        'positive lookahead',
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('(?!abc)'),
                      Text('negative lookahead'),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => print('Tapped Quantifiers and Alterations'),
                  child: Container(
                    child: const Text('Quantifiers and ALterations'),
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
                    width: 450,
                  )),
              ListTile(
                title: Table(
                  defaultVerticalAlignment:
                      TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
                  columnWidths: const <int, TableColumnWidth>{
                    0: FixedColumnWidth(5),
                    1: FixedColumnWidth(100),
                  },
                  children: const [
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('a* a+ a?'),
                      Text('0 or more, 1 or more, 0 or 1'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'a{5} a{2,}'),
                      Text('exactly five, two or more'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text(r'a{1,3}'),
                      Text('between one & three'),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('a+? a{2,}?'),
                      Text(
                        'match as few as possible',
                      ),
                    ]),
                    TableRow(decoration: BoxDecoration(), children: [
                      Text('ab|cd'),
                      Text('match ab or cd'),
                    ]),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: You would probably want to pass a `VoidCallback` as an argument to the child widgets constructor. Then, when you create the child widget within the parent widget, you could pass a function that calls `setState` as the `VoidCallback` argument. You could then invoke the argument from within the child widget whenever you are wanting the parent widget to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve such a task. The easiest would be to use a callback function, which you pass in as an argument to the child widget.

You could also try to lift state up using some state library like BLoC or Provider. You then build the parent when the state changes.

Some examples for the callback approach: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/lifting-state-up-and-callbacks-7a19d0bdbe53